# Where's the video editing play button?

Tags: interface

I'm a complete beginner with regard to Blender video editing.  I'm watching an instructional video.  To play the vid, he hits the play button.  Well, I haven't got a play button.  Now what?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the bottom where you see a video clip symbol and then words that say, "Sequencer," it's normally set to the Timeline panel where you would see a play button, but it's right now set to the "Video Editor" panel.  Just click on the video clip icon in the bottom left corner and choose "timeline" in the "animation" section.  Then the play button will appear.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Allah be praised for having mercy on me in this unbearably tantalizing situation.

Answer (score 1):

Press the <kbd>space bar</kbd> to start playback.

Then press it again to stop.

No need to use the mouse.